# Data Binding To Property C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I need to bind a textbox to a property in the code behind, but I want it to be just to a property instead of class,

Instead of this:

```
public class A
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

textbox.DataContext = A
<textbox Text="{Binding Text}"/>
```

I want this:

```
public string Text { get; set; }
textbox.DataContext = Text;
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to achieve this by using

```
<textbox Text="{Binding}"/>
```

Alternative approach is to use the same form as data context, and not change the binding:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

And in your XAML file leave the same binding:

```
<textbox Text="{Binding Text}"/>
```

In such case you would be binding to the property on your form class.

Comment: The first approach didn't work, it gave a run-time error... though the second approach did work so thanks!